# OneToMany and ManyToOne entities objects are linked in recursion

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

In my java-spring boot application I have a problem with 2 java classes with a parent-children bidirectional relationship with annotation @oneToMany and @ManyToOne.

When I try to save them on database sending a post request to the  controller's endpoint, is created a recursive loop  between the two objects persisted.
The same problem is present when I call the @getMapping(/{fatherId}) method in the controller.

Basically java receive a Father object witch contains a set of Children which reference their Father object , which contains their children list and so on and so on..

How can I fix this issue? I've seen some similar post which suggest using Jackson library annotations, is it the absolutely necessary to add it to the pom? I would prefer having the essential minimum set of packages referenced inside my pom and Jackson is not already in the default packages written using Spring Initializer(spring boot).

Thanks for every suggestions!

The parent class is **Father**:

```
@Entity
 @Table(name="Father")
 public class Father {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="father", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Child> children;
```

One Father can have many children but a child can have only one father.

The **child** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Child")
public class Child {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="ID_FATHER")
private Father father;
```

The endpoint in the controller is this:

```
@Transactional
@PostFather(path = "/newFather", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> createNewFather(@Valid @RequestBody Father father, BindingResult result) {



    Set<Child> childrenSet = new HashSet<Child>();
    //ArrayList<Child> newChildren= new ArrayList<Child>();
    //newChildren.addAll(father.getChildren());
    for (Child c : father.getChildren()) {
        Child newChild = new Child();
        newChild.setId(c.getId());
        newChild.setName(c.getName());
        newChild.setFather(father);

        fatherService.saveOrUpdateChild(newChild);
        childrenSet.add(newChild);
    }
    father.setChildren(childrenSet);
    Father newFather = fatherService.saveOrUpdateFather(father);


    return new ResponseEntity<Father>(newFather, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

@GetFather("/father/{fatherId}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getFatherById(@PathVariable int fatherId) {

    Father father = fatherService.findFatherById(fatherId);
    for (Child c : father.getChildren()) {// !!workaround to stop the loop!!
        c.setFather(null);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(father);

}
```

The Problem is that when I send to

*http://localhost:8080/api/myapi/newFather*

the Json post request    :

```
{
"name": "new father test 12",
"Children": [
    {
        "name": "Child test 12_1",
    },
    {
        "name": "Child test 12_2",
    },
 ]
}
```

I get as responce a loop:

```
{
   "id":197,
   "name":"father test 12",
   "children":[
      {
         "id":196,
         "name":"row test 12_1",
         "father":{
        "id":197,
        "name":"father test 12",
        "children":[
           {
              "id":196,
              "name":"row test 12_1",
              "father":{   /* ENDLESS LOOP !*/
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
  ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: you need to use `JsonbackReference` and `jsonManagedRefernece` to break infinite loop. check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61993704/stack-overflow-error-for-hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-with-spring-data-jpa/61996056#61996056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add @JsonIgnore annotation in the Father attribute in Child class

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="ID_FATHER")
@JsonIgnore
private Father father;
```

Comment: using this solve the loop in the Json response but in debug mode of intellijIdea If I pause execution in the controller method I still see the loop in the Father Object properties, Is there a way to fix also that?

Comment: It's just a behavior of your IDE debug mode, don't worry about it

Comment: And do you think is worth to add jackson dependency in the pom ? Or is it useful only for this ? I would have prefer  adding only packages which are essentials

Comment: Jackson is already included in springboot dependency